# How to have a clean unwanted characters in response from WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that send a response in XML format to client. when I test it with Soap UI it gave me some extra charactors. like  and also name space inside comment that is 'https://cf.ctr.com:DealerId' that is need to delete them. I am not sure where they come from.
This is the Response I am getting:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Body>
     <ProcessXMLResponse xmlns="https://cf.ctr.com">
     <ProcessXMLResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <StatusCode>201</StatusCode>
        <StatusDescription>XML Validation Fails</StatusDescription>
        <comments    xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
           <a:string/>
           <a:string>The element 'Collateral' in namespace   'https://cf.ctr.com' has invalid child element 'VIN' in namespace 'https://cf.ctr.com'. List of possible elements expected: 'Vehicle' in namespace 'https://cf.ctr.com'.</a:string>
           <a:string>The 'https://cf.ctr.com:DealerId' element is invalid - The value '104213' is invalid according to its datatype 'UnsignedShort' - The Pattern constraint failed.</a:string>
           <a:string>The 'https://https://cf.ctr.com:EmploymentPeriodInMonth' element is invalid - The value '0' is invalid according to its datatype 'Integer' - The MinInclusive constraint failed.</a:string>
           <a:string>The 'https://cf.ctr.com:Name' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.</a:string>
        </comments>
        <RemoteRefNumber>104213C3C4B606-2A10-46F4-87FA-E23</RemoteRefNumber>
     </ProcessXMLResult>
  </ProcessXMLResponse>
```

and this is my contracts:

```
  [DataContract(Namespace = "https://https://cf.ctr.com")]
public class PartnerRequest
{
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------   Username and Password in SOAP's Header - START



    [DataMember(Name = "username",Order=1)]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "password",Order=2)]
    public string password { get; set; }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------- Username and Password in SOAP's Header --- END

    // Body
    [DataMember(Name = "PartnerID", Order=3)] 
    public int PartnerID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PartnerName",Order=4)] 
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false,Name = "CFCConnect", Order = 5)] 
    public CFCConnect CFCConnect { get; set; }



}

[DataContract(Namespace = "https://cf.ctr.com")]
public class PartnerAuthentication
{
    public PartnerAuthentication()
    {

    }

    public PartnerAuthentication(PartnerAuthentication partner)
    {
        this.Authenticated = partner.Authenticated;
        this.StatusCode = partner.StatusCode;
        this.StatusDescription = partner.StatusDescription;
        this.comments = partner.comments;
        this.RemoteRefNumber = partner.RemoteRefNumber;

    }



    //[MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Namespace = "https://cf.ctr.com")]
     public bool Authenticated { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name = "StatusCode", Order = 1)] 
     public int StatusCode { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name = "StatusDescription", Order = 2)] 
     public string StatusDescription { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name = "comments", Order = 3)] 
     public List<string> comments { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name = "RemoteRefNumber", Order = 4)]
     public string RemoteRefNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no "extra" characters. The "extra" information is possibly needed when you reverse the process by deserializing the content into concrete types or parsing the schema e.g. "'https://cf.ctr.com:DealerId'" is namespace and property name in some schema.

It looks to me you are getting comments from some form of XSD validation engine which will give you full explanation why something is wrong e.g. "The 'https://cf.ctr.com:DealerId' element is invalid - The value '104213' is invalid according to its datatype 'UnsignedShort' - The Pattern constraint failed."

Passing XML as string on the wire is not a great idea. Deleting them is even more complicated and probably wrong direction.

Finally, why are you concerned how it looks on the wire? If your partner is sending you full stack dump of the problems in your comments you will have to transform them into something meaningful to you after you received it regardless how it looks on the wire.